# Hubot: How to specify the agent to be used by robot.http

Tags: node.js, proxy, hubot

I am in a corporate environment with a proxy, so I am using the stanza mentioned in the [Hubot documentation](https://hubot.github.com/docs/patterns/) under "Forwarding all HTTP requests through a proxy".

```
proxy = require 'proxy-agent'
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.globalHttpOptions.httpAgent  = proxy('http://my-proxy-server.internal', false)
  robot.globalHttpOptions.httpsAgent = proxy('http://my-proxy-server.internal', true)
```

That does the trick and Hubot can reach the Internet.

---

EDIT: Another question popped up in the mean time. What is the second parameter to `proxy` (`false` for http and `true` for https) doing? I fail to find this in the documentation and the source code?

---

However, I also have some (internal) resources that cannot be reached via the proxy. So I have coffee scripts where I do *not* want to/cannot use the proxy...

The same bit of [Hubot documentation](https://hubot.github.com/docs/patterns/) (same section) also states:

> For one-off control, use can specify an Agent to use with robot.http.

Disregarding what I think is a typo (`use` really should be `you`, I assume), I wonder *how* that can be done?

I basically want to *disable* the proxy for the requests from these "internal scripts". I tink that this should be possible by specifying that I want to use the default [Agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html). But how?

I tried about every thing I could come up with to no avail.

Comment: I found the answer to my EDIT (about the second parameter to `proxy`): it seems to be coming from an older version of [node-proxy-agent](https://preview.tinyurl.com/y8vhrtzy) (changed in 2.0.0 (e39c26)) and is not used any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the agent "pac aware" by using `pac+http` as the protocol to specify the proxy. That did the trick!

```
proxy = require 'proxy-agent'
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.globalHttpOptions.httpAgent  = proxy('pac+http://my-proxy-server.internal/proxy.pac', false)
  robot.globalHttpOptions.httpsAgent = proxy('pac+http://my-proxy- server.internal/proxy.pac', true)
```